# Simple PayPal Javascript API to pass product and amount

Tags: javascript, paypal

I would like to have a simple form with two textfields and a button:

- product id
- amount
- Checkout

When clicking on a button the default PayPal checkout appears with product id and an amount pre-populated. How do I achieve that with Javascript?

**update**

I would like to achieve this strictly using Javascript, no server side code such as PHP. It would work more like a generic PayPal button with two more textfields carrying product ID and amount.

**update 2**

Instead of searching for PayPal Javascript API, I should've searched for PayPal button custom amount. Looks like this will solve my question.

[Passing price variable to PayPal with custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255571/passing-price-variable-to-paypal-with-custom-button)

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

Comment: So, you would like... What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried finding any sort of documentation about it but no luck.

Comment: You didn't find any paypal tutorial? http://www.saaraan.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php / http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xvtlja_tutoriel-video-php-paypal-express-checkout_lifestyle#.UVXpXKucHhU

Comment: I didn't say I didn't find ANY, i.e. "ANY", meaning ANY,  paypal tutorial. I said I didn't find a documentation on how to do that with JS. I see a link you sent is PHP, not really what I wanted. It would be more as a version of generic PayPal checkout button with two more textfields.

Comment: I see you're posting more PHP links. Thank you, but that was not my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons

We've only recently released these, so they don't support all button types just yet (i.e. donations), but they'll work just fine for 'Buy now' buttons.

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID"
    data-button="buynow"
    data-name="My product"
    data-amount="1.00"
></script>
```

Comment: Does anyone know if parameters can be modified to let user choose Quantity of products on Paypal dialog?