# Passing custom PayPal payment fields

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment

So I'm trying to implement a PayPal payment field on my Wordpress site that has two custom fields where users can type in.

One, being invoice number

Two, being the price.

I found some code (untested) from another post here on stackoverflow, that is working as of 2013 (last post of the thread).

[Passing price variable to PayPal with custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255571/passing-price-variable-to-paypal-with-custom-button)

It has a text box where users can type in their custom price, and it gets passed to PayPal. I need to edit the form to allow the invoice number passing too. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Never used PayPal API before. All help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Payments">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://YOURSITE.com/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"     value="http://YOURSITE.com/payments.html">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working it out.

I had to change type="hidden" for the item_name to type="text".

Very simple fix, wasn't expecting it to be this easy!