# Not able to specify "amount" per payment request on PayPal HTMLButton

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate with PayPal using the "HTML Buttons" approach.
The checkout flow is rather simple, 
user clicks "Buy Now" -> transferred to PayPal -> payment processed -> returned to the site.

Based on the item that the customer wants to "Buy Now", the "amount" in the submitted form will vary, and I am unable to get PayPal to accept the value I am sending. I always see a text input which is empty when redirected to PayPal.

I tried hosted and unhosted buttons but still not able to see the desired effect.

hosted button HTML example:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HOSTEDBTNVALUE">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/SG/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="border: 0;">
  <img alt="" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" style="border: 0; width: 1; height: 1;">
  <input type="text" readonly="true" name="item_name" value="Test PayPal integration payment">
  <div class="form-group" id="amount_field">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="amount">Amount</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="100" aria-describedby="amount_info_0" class="form-control"><span id="amount_info_0" class="help-block">Real</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="txnRef_field">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txnRef">Transaction Ref</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" id="txnRef" name="txnRef" value="8d724ad470af4d9d91d49f84068c4bab" aria-describedby="txnRef_info_0" class="form-control"><span id="txnRef_info_0" class="help-block">Required</span></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SGD">
</form>
```

The "amount" above is a text input at the moment because this is my integration testing page, in the actual application it will be a hidden/readonly input embedded in the form.

Here is the unhosted button example code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----ReallyLongKey-----END PKCS7-----">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/SG/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="border: 0;"><img alt="" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" style="border: 0; width: 1; height: 1;">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://myapplication.com/transaction/paypal/status">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SGD">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="ad4a63e2f2f04b908ddb8e7c67f9c67a">
  <input type="text" readonly="true" name="item_name" value="Test PayPal integration payment">
  <div class="form-group" id="amount_field">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="amount">Amount</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="100" aria-describedby="amount_info_0" class="form-control"><span id="amount_info_0" class="help-block">Real</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="txnRef_field">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txnRef">Transaction Ref</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" id="txnRef" name="txnRef" value="ad4a63e2f2f04b908ddb8e7c67f9c67a" aria-describedby="txnRef_info_0" class="form-control"><span id="txnRef_info_0" class="help-block">Required</span></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have screenshots below for the application page and what I see as a result on the PayPal payment page. Please excuse the lack of alignment and styling. This is meant to be a proof of concept before it is pretty.

1. my application test page for integration
   [image]
2. paypal page where amount is expected to be fixed based on my request and not editable.
   [image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to try the simplest code possible if something doesn't work. Also, make sure to learn what each param [means](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). Additionally, try [the following code](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f1d8509af37bce4d1b3cde72fcb116ed). If it doesn't work for you, provide the code that paypal generate with default settings (when creating a button), please. There supposed to be no `hosted_button_id` param.

Comment: And like I said in the other question, when using hosted buttons, you can't override things like price in the form. Price is "hosted" on paypal. From what I remember.

Comment: @x-yuri thanks for the feedback. I was able to get it going by making PayPal generate the button with the following settings:
1. Merchant account IDs: Use my primary email address [did not use secure merchant account ID]
2. unchecking the "save button at PayPal" checkbox. 

Also, in the html button generation interface, I clicked the link "remove code protection" which made the "cmd" value from "_s-xclick" to "_xclick"

are there any concerns around the options I used?

Comment: I'm no expert in paypal, and it's been a while since I dealt with it, and I only have access to PayPal Personal account now. Having that said, I don't see anything wrong about the settings you chose. All those settings has to do with hiding what you pass to paypal, from what I can tell. Merchant ID to hide email, hosted buttons and encryption (code protection) is to hide all the data to be passed to paypal...

Comment: ...But as it often happens with security issues, you never know what can be used against you. So if easy to do, why not take some extra steps? IIRC, you can encrypt form data on your side, no need to use hosted buttons for that. As for hosted buttons, if it's just one or several buttons with static data, then it makes sense to host them. If not, than it'd most likely be a drag, if at all possible, so it makes sense to switch to non-hosted buttons. But it all depends on the project you're developing. Think about consequences should anything go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it going by making PayPal generate the button with the following settings: 
1. `Merchant account IDs: Use my primary email address` [did not use secure merchant account ID] 
2. unchecking the `save button at PayPal` checkbox. Also, in the html button generation interface, I clicked the link `remove code protection` which made the `cmd` value from `_s-xclick` to `_xclick`